# Unable to Zoom WMS above 20 in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, wms

I have multiple WMS layers. One of the layers is from a local GeoServer (UAV generated GeoTIFF). I am unable to zoom GeoTIFF up-to it's full resolution.

How to enable deep zoom in to WMS above 20% zoom level?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sample Web GIS using Leaflet and Geoserver</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:/Web_GIS/html/leaflet/leaflet.css"/>
    <script src="D:/Web_GIS/html/leaflet/leaflet.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #map {
            width: 600px;
            height: 400px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='map'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [9.34, 76.55],
        zoom: 20
    });
    var basemaps = {
        Countries: L.tileLayer.wms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
            layers: 'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries'
        }),

        Boundaries: L.tileLayer.wms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
            layers: 'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land'
        }),

        'Countries, then boundaries': L.tileLayer.wms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
            layers: 'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries,ne:ne_10m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land'
        }),

        'Boundaries, then countries': L.tileLayer.wms('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Geoserverworkspace/wms?', {
            layers: 'Geoserverworkspace:Geotiff'
        })
    };


    L.control.layers(basemaps, {}, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);
    basemaps.Countries.addTo(map);



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `minZoom` and `maxZoom`? https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#map-maxzoom

Comment: `L.tileLayer` has default 18 as `maxZoom` value and `L.tileLayer.wms` inherits this value. You have to set option `maxZoom` to desired value in your tile layer definition.

Comment: Note that the default value for a `L.TileLayer`'s `maxzoom` is documented at https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#tilelayer-maxzoom

Answer (score 9):

As Stefan mentioned, L.map has the option for setting minZoom and maxZoom.

```
   var map = L.map('map', {
            center: [9.34, 76.55],
            zoom: 20,           
            maxZoom: 25 //(or even higher)
        });
```

In your example, L.tileLayer.wms has that option, too:

```
Countries: L.tileLayer.wms('https://demo.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/ows?', {
            layers: 'ne:ne_10m_admin_0_countries',
            maxZoom: 28
)}
```